# np.zeros() missing required argument 'shape' (pos 1)

Tags: python, numpy

I'm working on a notebook from the Deeplearning.AI course and i've ran into an error, the problem was that I had initialize the parameters of the neural network with zeros:

```
# GRADED FUNCTION: initialize_with_zeros

def initialize_with_zeros(dim):
    """
    This function creates a vector of zeros of shape (dim, 1) for w and initializes b to 0.
    
    Argument:
    dim -- size of the w vector we want (or number of parameters in this case)
    
    Returns:
    w -- initialized vector of shape (dim, 1)
    b -- initialized scalar (corresponds to the bias) of type float
    """
    
    # (≈ 2 lines of code)
    #w = ...
    # b = ...
    # YOUR CODE STARTS HERE
    
    w = np.zeros((dim,1))
    b = np.zeros(dtype = float)
    
    # YOUR CODE ENDS HERE

    return w, b
```

I've filled in the correct shape at correct position in the argument but it does not seem to be working and i'm getting the following error :

```
dim = 2
w, b = initialize_with_zeros(dim)

assert type(b) == float
print ("w = " + str(w))
print ("b = " + str(b))

initialize_with_zeros_test(initialize_with_zeros)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBOQl.jpg)

Comment: Explain this expression `np.zeros(dtype = float)`

Answer (score 0):

You also need to give `b` a shape, even if it's a scalar:

```
b = np.zeros((1, ), dtype = float)
```

Answer (score -1):

The assertion that appears after your function is called wants the returned `b` value to be a single float, not an array. Just use:

```
b = 0.0
```